# Multiple type of controls in the same header in the datagrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, templates, datagrid, controls

I want to design the property window in Silverlight by using DataGrid. It will have two header columns. The value header can have the different types of controls. It might have combobox, textbox and other controls.
Here is the view for the datagrid.

1. Name--------------Type of the control(Control to display)
2. DisplayText-------TextBox
3. Type--------------ComboBox
4. IsEnabled---------CheckBox

If it is not possible in the datagrid then please suggest some other way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at DataForm?  I'm not sure why you'd want to do do the above in a DataGrid.

Comment: I tried the dataform and this is good for me. but I want few more requirement like if there is any class type variable then I want to show a button which will open a pop-up window to display the properties of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I used a converter that returned a control.
The converter created databinding to the source object
The datagrid datasource is a `IEnumerable<PropertyPresenter>`

```
    public class PropertyPresenter
    {
        public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
        public object Source { get; set; }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        FrameworkElement Control = null;
        var presenter = value as PropertyPresenter;

        Binding binding = new Binding(presenter.PropertyInfo.Name);
        binding.Mode = presenter.PropertyInfo.CanWrite ? BindingMode.TwoWay : BindingMode.OneWay;
        binding.Source = presenter.Source;

        if(presenter.PropertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            Control = new CheckBox();
            Control.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            Control.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
        }
        return Control;
    }
```